# How to do a page redirect in lift

Tags: scala, lift

I have the need to be able to redirect the current page request to a news page url.

Based on the params of the incoming request I retrieve data from the database and in case nothing is found I redirect the user to another page.

This is very easy to do in MVC but due to my inexperience with the view-first paradigm it is not very clear what the best way to do this is.

Kind regards,

Jaron

Answer (score 4):

Do you require anything else than?

```
S.redirectTo(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried method **RedirectTo** of object **JsCmds**? [[doc of this here]](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.2/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds%24object.html)

It is javascript-based redirect, which is using location.href call, but it could help you.

good luck